# Spring RMI over what protocol?

Tags: java, spring, protocols, remoting, rmi

I'm using spring remoting with rmi. Application works fine. But one thing in totally unclear for me: what protocol does spring use in its rmi support?

**Update:** Default is JRMP, I know this. JRMP or IIOP goes with Spring Remoting this is the question!

Comment: Java's RMI. Think it's default port is 1099

Answer (score 0):

RMI is its own protocol: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation

Answer (score 0):

RMI uses Java serialization to send objects over the wire between components.